# Interceptar redirecionamento de pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho uma página cujo o cliente está selecionando itens, depois de selecionado eu precisava verificar se o cliente irá deixar a pagina atual pois preciso alerta-lo com uma mensagem do tipo "Você quer salvar seu carrinho antes de deixar a página?" se sim salva e continua o redirect, se não só redireciona. Eu queria fazer para redirects globais pois eu poderia fazer aparecer um pop-up perguntando se ele queria e se depois fazer um window.location.href mas quero que sirva para todos e não fazer um por um os redirects... Consegui um método javascript que faz uma ação antes de redirecionar, mas mesmo mostrando um pop-up ele redireciona sem esperar resposta do cliente. Eu quero saber se tem como eu interceptar o redirect e depois da resposta dele eu deixa-lo redirecionar

A função js

```
 $(window).on("beforeunload", function(){
    console.log("Deixando a pagina");
    $('#modal-form-call').iziModal('open');
});
```

porém ali no form ele não aguarda a resposta e já redireciona

Answer (score 1):

Os navegadores tendem cada vez mais a bloquear esse tipo de coisa.

Se você tentar usar uma função `confirm` no evento `beforeUnload`, para ser mais assertivo por exemplo, o Chrome bloqueia a chamada da função. Acredito que os demais navegadores façam o mesmo.

Se não me engano, já vi pessoas fazerem perguntas sobre como burlar esse tipo de comportamento, para extensões ou coisas do tipo. Não me surpreenderia se algum *ad blocker* da vida começasse a mexer com isso.

Por essas razões, acredito que interromper o fluxo mais natural das ações do usuário não é um bom caminho. Eu continuaria essa pesquisa *se-e-somente-se* isso for um requisito por motivos de lei - eu sei que na Europa existem leis relacionadas a como você pode se comunicar com seus usuários em sua página.

Porém, se isso for apenas uma *feature*, minha sugestão é sempre salvar o carrinho no armazenamento local do navegador (e possivelmente no servidor também) a cada alteração no carrinho. Isso dá uma experiência muito mais agradável ao usuário e você não fica se preocupando com fluxos e subfluxos de interface, nem em tentar convencer o navegador e suas extensões sobre seu código não ser malicioso.